# Javascript to remove text

Tags: javascript, dom

I am trying to remove the text, "Hi Mom" from an html page using javascript after it loads.

I can not use any framework like jQuery.

I can use the DOM, but will not know where it is, other than it's wrapped in a  tag somewhere.

Can this be done in plain old Javascript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a pretty simple DOM walk you can do.

There could be improvements if you thought there may be more than once occurrence in the same text node, but it doesn't sound like that's the case.

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/UrNWb/

```
var text_to_remove = "Hi Mom";

function dom_walk( el ) {
    if( el.nodeType === 1 && el.childNodes.length ) {
        if( el.nodeName.toLowerCase() !== 'script' ) {
            for( var i = 0; i < el.childNodes.length; i++ ) {
                dom_walk( el.childNodes[ i ] );
            }
        }
    } else if( el.nodeType === 3 ) {
        if( el.data.indexOf( text_to_remove ) !== -1 ) {
            el.data = el.data.replace( text_to_remove, '' );
        }
    }
}

dom_walk( document.body );
```

Comment: Cool, but the indexOf test seem redundant, why not just do the replacement (and save a line of code). Also don't understand the test for el.childNodes.length, if it's zero the for loop will be skipped anyway.

Comment: @RobG: I'm banking on the idea that `indexOf` is a faster operation than the `.replace()` + reassignment. And with the `.length`, I'm just trying to avoid the extra work inside the `if` when possible, like `toLowerCase()`, but you're right, it could be eliminated.

Comment: ...but then I guess in the case of a script, the `.length` won't likely be `0`, so there's really no point. EDIT: Actually, I just did a test, and at least in Chrome, I get `0` length for `childNodes` of a `<script>`. If that's consistent, then I could get rid of the `"script"` test altogether.

Answer (score 1):

Easiest solution:

```
function removeText(s) {
  var el, els = document.getElementsByTagName('*');
  var node, nodes;

  for (var i=0, iLen=els.length; i<iLen; i++) {
    el = els[i];

    if (el.tagName.toLowerCase() != 'script') {
      nodes = el.childNodes;
    } else {
      nodes = [];
    }

    for (var j=0, jLen=nodes.length; j<jLen; j++) {
      node = nodes[j];

      if (node.nodeType == 3) {
        node.data = node.data.replace(s, '');
      }
    }
  }
}

window.onload = function() {
  removeText('hi mom');
}
```

You could also do a recursive version, but the above is just simpler.

Answer (score -1):

`document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replace("Hi Mom", "")` should be a decent start.

Comment: Destroying and restoring your entire DOM structure isn't a good practice.

Comment: You just destroyed every listener in the document that isn't inline, and probably destroyed quite a few properties and default attributes along the way.